# Toast for Spinner (Nothing Selected)

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, android-toast

Hi i would like to add toast for my Spinner. The message must be displayed when nothing is selected. 
Below is my spinner declaration and example of get text toast :

```
  if (fromEditText.getText().toString().length() < 1) {
                Toast.makeText(GlownaAstronomia.this, "Musisz wpisać dowolną liczbę", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                String fromString = (String) fromSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String toString = (String) toSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                double input = Double.valueOf(fromEditText.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how Spinner Listener Works and for Me Too

Here is Steps for spinner Listener

**1) Make Object Of Spinner at class level**

```
Spinner My_Spinner;
```

**2) Get Reference of Spinner from XML**

```
My_Spinner= (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Spinner);
```

**3)Implements Listeners on Class**

```
implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

**4)Set Listener to Spinner**

```
My_Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

**5)Override Methods of Spinner Listener and Add Toast To It**

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Here is Spinner Calling,Value is "+My_Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Here Your Text For Toast  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
      }
         @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Here Your Text For Nothing Selected Toast  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user a listener :

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()    {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // Display the toast here
    }

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Better approach can be to add a "NA" value to your spinner to avoid confusion.

Then you can check the spinner text and launch the toast if required.

NA- Not Applicable.